# What is the best way when using collections with empty elements in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I pass an array of elements in the action method [image]

But I get the collection of only one element, because in my case, I have not all indexes

[image]
What is the best way when using collections with empty elements?

Comment: Why do you numberize them?

Comment: @Grumbler85 Because he has to - they have sub-properties.

Comment: You will need to adjust your indices to make them contiguous (1, 2, 3, 4...) using JavaScript or some other method - it's not possible to give you any more detail without knowing how the inputs are constructed.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/

Comment: @AntP I can do this with js, but I wanted to know whether it is possible to take a collection with incomplete indexes

Comment: @kriper The only way to do that is to exclude the indices altogether but then you can't specify which sub-properties belong where (this will only work well for scalar values). You could try binding to a `Dictionary<int,YourClass>` instead and then iterating over values... that *might* work.